# Haskell package for sampling from standard probability distributions

Tags: haskell, random

I would like to do some Monte Carlo analysis in Haskell. I would like to be able to write code like this:

```
do n <- poisson lambda
   xs <- replicateM n $ normal mu sigma
   return $ maximum xs
```

which corresponds to the stochastic model

```
n ~ Poisson(lambda)
for (i in 1:n)
  x[i] ~ Normal(mu, sigma)
y = max_{i=1}^n x[i]
```

I can see how to create the necessary random-sampling monad pretty easily. However, I would prefer not to have to implement samplers for all of the standard probability distributions. Is there a Haskell package that already has these implemented?

I have looked at package `random-fu`, which has been stalled at version 0.2.7 for three years, but I can't make sense of it; it depends on typeclasses `MonadRandom` and `RandomSource`, which aren't well explained.

I've also looked at package `mwc-probability`, but I can't make sense of it either -- it seems you have to already understand the `PrimMonad` and `PrimState` typeclasses.

Both of these packages strike me as having overly complex APIs, and seem to have entirely abandoned the standard random-number-generation framework of Haskell as found in `System.Random`.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: How about statistics package?

Comment: Same issue with the statistics package -- I get lost when I get down to the section on random number generation and it starts using `PrimState` and `PrimMonad` in the function signatures. Whatever happened to `System.Random.RandomGen`?

Comment: How about `probable`? Seems to have some simple examples, works with distributions from statistics, updated recently.

Comment: Same issue with `PrimState` and `PrimMonad` again. And trying to figure out where the standard `System.Random.RandomGen` fits in here, if at all.

Comment: Q: What happened to `System.Random.RandomGen`? A: It's slow and not very random, so people use better generators (that are, generally, both faster and less predictable) whenever they can. No sense whining about it; instead, take this as an opportunity to learn more about Haskell as you dig into the complicated API. (Yes, every part of the complication is well-motivated by technical considerations.)

Comment: OK, but where do I find a good explanation of `Gen`, `PrimState`, and `PrimMonad`? The official documentation is pretty opaque. And... as far as I can tell, these packages seem to have the underlying PRNG hard-wired in, which is _very much_ contrary to the spirit of Haskell. (I hope this isn't actually the case!)

Comment: @KevinS.VanHorn I'm not sure where you're getting the idea of a "hard coded" random source from. That's absolutely not the case. You always have to provide your own source of randomness with these packages.

Comment: There are good answers to many of the questions you've raised in comments -- it's not that hard to explain what `PrimMonad` is (and why it's used), and I believe you can use a `RandomGen` instance as a `random-fu` RNG without too much pain.  However, these answers won't fit in comments, and they aren't answers to the original question.  Perhaps you could post these as additional questions?

Comment: @cubic, AFAICT, all random variable generation in the package `statistics` requires an argument of the very specific type `Gen (PrimState m)`, and ultimately goes through `System.Random.MWC.uniform`, which ultimately calls `uniformWord32`, a very specific pseudo-random number generator that implements Marsaglia's MWC256 algorithm. This is  hard-wired in; there is no way for me to substitute in a different PRNG. The same seems to apply to all of these packages.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, if you want to be able to write code like this:

```
do n <- poisson lambda
   xs <- replicateM n $ normal mu sigma
   return $ maximum xs
```

then you presumably want to use `random-fu`:

```
import Control.Monad
import Data.Random
import Data.Random.Distribution.Poisson
import Data.Random.Distribution.Normal

foo :: RVar Double
foo = do
  n <- poisson lambda
  xs <- replicateM (n+1) $ normal mu sigma
  return $ maximum xs

  where lambda = 10 :: Double
        mu = 0
        sigma = 6

main :: IO ()
main = print =<< replicateM 10 (sample foo)
```

I'm not sure that lack of updates over the past three years should be a deciding factor.  Have there really been *that* many exciting advances in the world of gamma distributions?

Actually, it looks like `mwc-probability` works about the same:

```
import Control.Monad
import System.Random.MWC.Probability

foo :: Prob IO Double
foo = do
  n <- poisson lambda
  xs <- replicateM (n+1) $ normal mu sigma
  return $ maximum xs

  where lambda = 10 :: Double
        mu = 0
        sigma = 6

main :: IO ()
main = do
  gen <- createSystemRandom
  print =<< replicateM 10 (sample foo gen)
```

Comment: Thanks, that's a nice example. But the deciding factor is really that I can't figure out what the underlying source of random bits is in your example, or how to provide the underlying RNG in general. When I look at the documentation for `sample`, I see that I need to understand the typeclasses `Sampleable` and `MonadRandom`. The latter has barely any documentation -- not even a list of required methods! The former requires me to understand `RandomSource` and, possibly, `Lift`. The documentation for both of those is quite sparse.

Comment: Similar comment with `mwc-probability` -- it's unclear where the underlying RNG is coming from, and function signatures for random variate generation refer to the mysterious typeclasses `PrimState` and `PrimMonad`. What happened to `System.Random.RandomGen`?

Comment: Ah, in that case the answer is no, there is no (reasonably popular and maintained) Haskell package that includes samplers for a standard set of probability distributions, is well documented, can be understood without reference to a `MonadRandom` or mechanism of similar complexity, and would also support a monadic syntax similar to what you describe.

Comment: @KevinS.VanHorn sounds like maybe it's time to level up your haskell-fu?  Try to understand despite the sparse documentation.  It's all open source after all.  Ask questions when you get stuck, we're here to help!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the packages `mwc-random` and `statistics` sufficiently to make them usable for my purposes. To make them easier to use, I defined some wrappers, described below. The complete set of packages my solution uses is `transformers`, `vector`, `mwc-random`, and `statistics`.

First, here are the needed language extensions and imports:

```
{-# LANGUAGE RankNTypes #-}
{-# LANGUAGE FlexibleContexts #-}

import Control.Monad (replicateM)
import Control.Monad.ST
import Control.Monad.Trans.Reader
import qualified Data.Vector as V
import Data.Vector.Generic hiding (replicateM, sum, product)
import Data.Word
import System.Random.MWC (Gen)
import qualified System.Random.MWC as R
import Statistics.Distribution
import Statistics.Distribution.Normal
```

I define a random-sampling monad `Rand` that hides from the user the need to understand `PrimMonad` and `PrimState`, and provides some needed utilities. (If you're interested in the details, `Gen s a` is a uniform PRNG that returns values of type `a`, `ST s` is a state-transformer monad, and the uninstantiated type variable `s` is part of a type-system hack that prevents state-updating side effects from escaping the monad.) An unfortunate feature of the `mwc-random` and `statistics` packages is that the primitive PRNG, based on Marsaglia's MWC256 algorithm, is hardwired-in; you cannot substitute a different PRNG.

```
type Rand0 s a = ReaderT (Gen s) (ST s) a
type Rand a = (forall s. Rand0 s a)  -- the random-sampling monad

-- A draw from the Uniform(0.0, 1.0) distribution
uniform01 :: Rand Double
uniform01 = ask >>= R.uniform

-- Provide a seed for the PRNG and return a draw from the random sampler
runRandL :: Rand a -> [Word32] -> a
runRandL rand seeds = runRandV rand (V.fromList seeds)

-- Provide a seed for the PRNG and return a draw from the random sampler
runRandV :: Vector v Word32 => Rand a -> v Word32 -> a
runRandV rand seeds =
  runST $ R.initialize seeds >>= runReaderT rand

-- Seed the PRNG with data from the system's fast source of pseudo-random numbers,
-- then return a draw from the random sampler
runRandIO :: Rand a -> IO a
runRandIO rand = do
  gen <- R.createSystemRandom
  seeds <- R.fromSeed <$> R.save gen
  return $ runRandV rand seeds
```

If you have `f :: Rand a` and you want `n` independent draws from `f`, then use `replicateM f :: Rand [a]` or `V.replicateM f :: Rand (V.Vector a)`. The following example returns a draw from the sum of `n` independent uniform random variables:

```
sumOfUniform :: Int -> Rand Double
sumOfUniform n = do
  xs <- replicateM n uniform01
  return $ sum xs
```

The `statistics` package provides various data types that correspond to common statistical distributions. For example, `normalDistr mu sigma :: NormalDistribution` is an object representing a normal distribution; it contains the parameter values `mu` for the mean and `sigma` for the std deviation.

Instances of type class `ContDistr d` provide density and inverse CDF (quantile) functions for objects of distribution type `d`.

Instances of type class `ContGen d` provide a `genContVar` function for drawing from a continuous distribution, and instances of type class `DiscrGen d` provide a `genDiscrVar` function for drawing from a discrete distribution.

To make all of this easy to use with the `Rand` monad, I define some wrappers:

```
-- Draw from the continuous distribution d
genContV :: ContGen d => d -> Rand Double
genContV d = ask >>= genContVar d

-- Draw from the discrete distribution d
genDiscrV :: DiscreteGen d => d -> Rand Int
genDiscrV d = ask >>= genDiscreteVar d

-- Draw from the continuous distribution d using the inverse CDF method.
genCont :: ContDistr d => d -> Rand Double
genCont d = ask >>= genContinuous d

-- Draw from the normal distribution with mean mu and std dev sigma
normal :: Double -> Double -> Rand Double
normal mu sigma = genContV $ normalDistr mu sigma
```

Wrappers for other distributions (exponential, beta, gamma, etc.) follow the same pattern as the wrapper for normal distributions.

As a final example, here is a draw from the product of two normally-distributed random variables:

```
productOf2Normals :: Double -> Double -> Rand Double
productOf2Normals mu sigma = do
  x1 <- normal mu sigma
  x2 <- normal mu sigma
  return $ x1 * x2
```